# How to stylise a new menu bar bootstrap and wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

im trying to add a new class menu for my footer. how do i chg the colors, active , etc

i add this to my custom css file

```
.navbar-rodape { background-color: none;}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { background-color: #000000}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { background-color: #080808}
.dropdown-menu { background-color: #FFFFFF}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-color: #ED7913}
.navbar-rodape { background-image: none; }
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-image: none; }
.navbar-rodape { border-color: #080808}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-brand { color: #999999}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-brand:hover { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #999999}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-rodape .navbar-        nav>.active>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.dropdown-menu>li>a { color: #333333}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-top-color: #999999}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-top-color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-bottom-color: #999999}
.navbar-rodape .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF}
```

so when i call the menu

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <h4>Desporto</h4>
        <nav id="footermenu1" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" role="navigation">
        <?php  wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer_menu_desporto', 'container'=> false , 'menu_class' => 'navbar-rodape')); ?>
               </nav>
</div>
```

doest assume the new style ? what im doing wrong ?

thz in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Hi you try this code it helps

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme--wp-33410

https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker